# Proof that coordinate lines are lines of curvature

Tags: proof-writing, surfaces, curvature

Prove that the coordinate lines of a surface patch are lines of curvature if and only if $f=F=0$.

Lines of curvature being defined as follows: A unit-speed curve $\gamma:I\rightarrow S$ in an oriented regular surface S is called a line of curvature if $\gamma'(t)$ is a principle direction for all $t∈  I$

I started with the equation for Gaussian curvature $K=\frac{eg-f^2}{EG-F^2}$, and with $f=F=0$, I have $K=\frac{eg}{EG}=\frac{e}{E}*\frac{g}{G}$

And Mean curvature $H=\frac{eG-2fF+gE}{2(EG-F^2)}=\frac{eg+gE}{2EG}=\frac{e}{E}+\frac{g}{G}$

Principle curvatures $k_1$ and $k_2$ as $k_1 +k_2=2H, k_1k_2=K$.

I'm having trouble understanding how to incorporate $\gamma$ as a principle direction and beginning the proof. Any direction of help would be great, thanks.

Comment: You're failing to use the definition of a principal direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for a patch $x\colon U\subset \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$, the vectors $x_u$ and $x_v$ are the tangent vectors of the $u$- and $v$-lines. A $u$-line is parametrized by $\gamma(t)= x(t,v_0)$ with $v_0$ constant; $v$-lines are parametrized by $\gamma(t)=x(u_0,t)$ with constant $u_0$.

What do you now have to show? Well, you need to show that, at every point, $x_u$ and $x_v$ are eigenvectors of the shape operator. For this, you have to show that the matrix of the shape operator (w.r.t. the basis $x_u$, $x_v$) is diagonal.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with shape operators. They have not come up when dealing with this kind of problem

Comment: Well, which definition of a a principal direction do you use?

Comment: The eigenvectors {v1,v2}  are an orthonormal basis of TpS with respect to which the Weingarten map is represented by a diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues k1 and k2. The eigenvectors v1 and v2 are called principal directions of S at p.

Comment: I guess the shape operator is the same thing as the weingarten map after some reading

Comment: I got it now thank you for the direction